# Nunjucks for Duktape (Jinja2 / Django) like templates compiler to byte code

Tags: javascript, templating

Looking for a port of [Nunjucks](http://jlongster.com/Introducing-Nunjucks,-a-Better-Javascript-Templating-System) or any other of Jijna2 like tempting system implementation what compiles the templates into the [Duktape](http://duktape.org) vm/byte code (ECMAscript engine).

More precisely, not exactly must be Jinja2, any templating engine is OK what allows/has:

- template inheritance
- sandboxed execution mode
- includes
- user-defined methods (blocks)
- unicode suport
- open-source (ofc) :)

e.g. the Jinja2 is ideal, just the templates should be compiled not only to Javascript (similarly as Nunjucks does) but into Duktape bytecode for sandboxed execution. Duktape allows byte code execution regardless of the host environment, unfortunately the Nunjucks is for the node.js.

In short - the ideal solution would be a variant of the Nunjucks what compiles into Duktape's byte code.

Motivation: having one such engine, could allow its easy port into any Duktape/host environments, like

- [Duktape for node.js](https://github.com/ndob/duktape-node)
- [Duktape for ruby](https://github.com/judofyr/duktape.rb)
- [Duktape for perl](https://github.com/mamod/JavaScript-Duktape)
- and of course Duktape for C (default)

what could finally solve the true **cross-platform**, **sandboxed**, template-engine problem. ;)